# .Net Core project keeps referencing other project instead of Nuget package of same name

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I seem to be having the same problem as [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40184782/878701).

> NOTE: Ordinarily, I'd avoid the repost, but the lack of an answer and the low traffic seemed to warrant a refresh into the SO feed.

### The setup

1. Create two .Net Core projects (**A** & **B**) in two *separate* solutions in the same folder.  From **A**, create a Nuget package.  (You can upload it to Nuget, MyGet, or just keep locally.  Just make sure the source is configured.)
2. In **B**, add the Nuget package.

### The result

Project **A** has now been added to the solution for Project **B**.

### The questions

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I get VS to recognize that it should be referencing the Nuget package, not the project?

### Other stuff

I'm running VS 2015 Pro Update 3 on Windows 10.

In my real scenario, my Nuget package is at a later version.  When I open the *project.json* file, I get a compiler warning on the `ProjectA` dependency that says I'm depending on version 1.1, but version 1.0 is found.

I've created [an example on GitHub](https://github.com/gregsdennis/StackOverflow_42357785) for you to play around with.

Comment: You should not be reposting the same question. The correct method is to put a bounty on the other question instead.

Comment: but mine includes specifics and an example replicating the problem.

Comment: If it's the same question and will have the same answer, it's a duplicate. You can improve the question though...

Comment: Very well.  Once my edit is approved, I'll close this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must place the solutions into separate directories as .NET Core Projects in VS2015 has unique file system requirements, and will behave poorly when you put them in the same directory (each solution will generate a hidden `.vs` folder, and they will end up overlapping).

For example you could change the directory structure to this:

```
.\Solutions\A\ <-- Directory for Solution A
.\Solutions\B\ <-- Directory for Solution B
.\A\ <-- Project A
.\B\ <-- Project B
```

This would mean that the hidden `.vs` folders for each solution will no longer overlap (ie, the solutions do not share this)

```
.\Solutions\A\ProjectA.sln
.\Solutions\A\global.json
.\Solutions\A\.vs\

.\Solutions\B\ProjectB.sln
.\Solutions\B\global.json
.\Solutions\B\.vs\
```

Comment: @gregsdennis no problem... to argue in your favor, if you didn't re-post this question, I would have never seen it.

Comment: I also had to use @mickaël-derriey's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Local projects take precedence over NuGet packages. I don't know at what level this is baked-in, though.

The solution is to explicitly specify in your `project.json` that you want to reference a NuGet package and not the project in the same solution.

```
"YourNuGetPackageName": {
    "target": "package",
    "version": "VersionOfYourNuGetPackage"
}
```

You can have a look at an example [here](https://github.com/mderriey/octokit.net/blob/2f3c89fc6b693af15ee66b91a8eef983d1fb61d1/build/project.json).

Comment: I couldn't get this working.  I would have preferred this to the independent solution folders option.  Also, the example above doesn't match the example in the link.

Comment: sorry about the typo, I edited the answer. what didn't work?

Comment: I went back and looked at it.  Apparently, I had left this in.  This, combined with @Svek's answer resolved my problem.